# Is there a good ASP.NET package to implement StackExchange-style authentication and profiles

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm familiar with ASP.NET Membership, Profile, forms auth, etc., as well as OpenId/OAuth.  However, I haven't found a great resource on rolling together a really smart, modern OpenId-enabled login and profile system similar to what StackExchange does.  Is there a package or template that adds in StackExchange-like authentication and profiles?  Ideally, what I'm looking for has these features:

- NuGet installation into an existing MVC project OR a starter template for MVC
- Allows authentication with OpenId, FaceBook, Twitter, or in-site with a clean UI
- Allows associating FaceBook and Twitter OAuth with an existing account that may or may not use OpenId.
- Allows merging and modifying multiple authentication methods, similar to the way StackOverlow does if you log in with multiple methods.

DotNetOpenAuth comes close, but still relies on a developer to handle the more complex cases of merging logins and associating OAuth tokens with users.  It seems like there would be a good base template or package by now that gives you a full modern authentication story fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [StackId](http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/checkout) could be useful. It's built on top of DotNetOpenAuth by StackExchange team.
You can find its description in [the list of StackExcnage open source projects](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-open-source-projects/). But it doesn't have Nuget package.

Comment: Looks very promising.  I will check this out.